# Why does the spin of a particle decides its nature in the Standard Model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, standard-model

Like gluons are spin 1 particles that are responsible for the nuclear forces, gravitons are spin 2 particles that are said to carry the force of gravity. My question is why the nature of a particle is dependant on its spin?

Answer (score 2):

As this is a complicated issue, I'll summarise some technical details with links to better explanations.

1. Identical particles that live in at least $3$ spatial dimensions must (i) have integer or half-odd-integer spin and (ii) have wavefunctions that are either symmetric or antisymmetric under their exchange in pairs. ([Anyonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon) statistics is possible instead in $2$-dimensional systems such as graphene, because $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \left\{ 0\right\}$ is not simply connected.)
2. The [spin-statistics theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem) establishes that physical quantum fields obey Einstein-Bose statistics if their quanta have integer spin, or Fermi-Dirac statistics if their quanta have half-odd-integer spin. There are several ways to prove this, but the crux of the argument is that the eigenenergies of the Hamiltonian for a field breaking this rule wouldn't be bounded below.
3. The word "physical" warrants an explanation here. Take, for example, [Faddeev-Popov ghosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93Popov_ghost) (introduced in BRST quantisation), which obey Fermi-Dirac statistics but have integer spin. Feynman diagrams confine such ghosts to their internal lines, whereas physical particles are allowed on the external legs. We can prove the FP fields obey Fermi-Dirac statistics by considering a classical theory of them, in which they are [Grassmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number)-valued; we can also use this classical field theory to check the spin. For example, the $-i\sum_a\partial_\mu\bar{c}^aD^\mu c^a$ term in the Yang-Mills Lagrangian equips the FP fields $c,\,\bar{c}$ with no Greek indices, as they are spin-0. (In perturbative quantum gravity we obtain spin-1 FP fields.)
4. A similar analysis tells us that the toy model $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-V(\phi)$ has a single spin-$0$ scalar bosonic field $\phi$, that the electromagnetic $A_\mu$ (the photon) and its Yang-Mills counterparts (the other gauge bosons of the standard model) are spin-$1$ vector bosons, and the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ (the graviton) is spin-$2$.
5. But how would one guess the spin of gauge bosons without a Lagrangian? As discussed in Sec. 1.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.00319.pdf), spin-$1$ forces causes like to repel (e.g. positive charges), whereas spin-$0$ and spin-$2$ forces cause like to attract (e.g. positive masses), and a spin-$0$ model of gravity is ruled out because gravity couples to relativistic mass-energy. This "spin-$1$ repels, other spins attract" rule requires a spin-by-spin calculation beyond the scope of that link, but see e.g. Chapters I.4 and I.5 of A Zee's *Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell*.
6. I recommend you read Zee's treatment or a similar one, so you can see that "virtual particles" are integrated over to compute interactions associated with integer-spin fields. Indeed, one need not dream up virtual particles as a concept to do this calculation; it requires only the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics he develops in I.2 and I.3. In particular, half-odd-integer force carriers are impossible because the calculation finds the coefficient, in the scalar-valued action, of a quadratic current term.
7. Why does nature even have an $A_\mu$ in the first place? A [toy model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_electrodynamics) shows how introducing a vector field can promote a global symmetry to a local one. The reference I linked under point 5 above discusses this idea in its Sec 1.2, and explains an analogous motivation of gravity in Sec. 1.3. In the Standard Model, the toy model above is promoted to one that has spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ charged fermions instead of charged scalars.

Answer (score -2):

All of the "matter" particles have spin 1/2.  All of the force carriers have integer spin.

Now as to "what was mother nature thinking when she endowed particles with the particular spins that she chose for them"? I suppose you could think of it like this:  when a spin up electron emits a photon, the electron changes to a spin down electron.  It goes from having an angular momentum of +1/2 to -(1/2), for a change of 1.  Note that the photon the was emitted was a spin-1 particle.

The math above is oversimplified just a bit, but I think it illustrates how the universe and the forces within it would work rather differently (or not at all) if mother nature made spins any other way.

Lastly, I'm sure you could come up with other viable ways that mother nature could have arranged how she assigned spins to particles, but at least now you have something to start with.

Hope this helps.